# Can you send a unix domain file descriptor over another unix domain socket in node.js?

Tags: node.js, sockets

In Node.js. 
Is it possible to send a unix domain socket file descriptor over already established unix domain socket ?

I have the following example but I am not sure how and if it's even possible to receive the file descriptor on the other end in usable form.

currently getting file descriptor type error on the server side

In the example I have the client connecting to the server side via unix socket and that works fine, then once the connection is established I try to create a new server with new unix socket and pass that file descriptor to the server so server can use it.

Server side:

```
var net = require('net');
var socket = '/tmp/testing.node.sock';
var fs = require('fs');

if (fs.existsSync(socket)) {
    fs.unlinkSync(socket);
}


var server = net.createServer(function(c) { 
    console.log('server connected');
    c.on('end', function() {
        console.log('server disconnected');
    });
    c.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    });

    c.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log("data received");
        console.log(data.toString());

        // creating new socket with passed fd
        var newsock = new net.Socket({fd:data}); // how do I convert it here to file descriptor - if even possible 
        console.log(newsock);
    });
});



server.listen(socket, function() { 
    console.log('server bound');


});
```

client side:

```
var net = require('net');
var socket = '/host/testing.node.sock';
var fs = require('fs');

client = net.connect({path: socket}, function () {

    // here we create a new server that we want the fd passed to other server
    var newSock = '/tmp/testing.node.sock';
    if (fs.existsSync(newSock)) {
        fs.unlinkSync(newSock);
    }
    // create a new server 
    var server = net.createServer(function (c) { //'connection' listener
        console.log('server connected');
        c.on('end', function () {
            console.log('server disconnected');
        });
        c.on('error', function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        });

        c.on('data', function (data) {
            console.log("data received");
            console.log(data);
        });

    });


    server.listen(newSock, function () { //'listening' listener
        console.log('server bound');

        console.log(server);

        // here we want to pass the new fd 
        client.write(new Buffer(server._handle.fd));
    });


});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Back in node v0.4 this functionality existed for both [sending](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.4/src/node_net.cc#L1028-L1137) and [receiving](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.4/src/node_net.cc#L859-L949) but it was later removed. You'll have to write your own binding to allow you to send/receive file descriptors on an existing fd (your unix domain socket, whose fd should be accessible in node IIRC). [Here](http://www.normalesup.org/~george/comp/libancillary/) [are](http://vpj.svbtle.com/passing-file-descriptors-between-processes-using-sendmsg-and-recvmsg) [some](http://keithp.com/blogs/fd-passing/) links to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

As described in https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/345,
Node doesn't support this anymore because there's no way to do it on Windows.  But this package provides a UNIX socket API that can send file descriptors: https://www.npmjs.com/package/usocket